# How to know the supported parameter for the --oformat flag of linkers in LLVM?

Tags: linker, llvm, ld

LLVM binaries are all cross-tools in nature, different llvm linker tools (e.g. ld.lld.exe/ld-link.exe) are just drivers to emulate different native linkers (e.g. GNU ld/Windows link.exe) which are based on the same LLVM linker core. So each of this should be able to generated binaries for different target formats, like PE or ELF on any host platform.

Take ld.lld.exe on Windows 10 as example,

```
ld.lld.exe --oformat elf -o test.exe main.o
```

works (test.exe can't be run for Windows for sure), but "--oformat pe" or "--oformat coff" doesn't work.

I'm aware that ld-link is easier to generate PE executable, but the purpose here is to experiment with the cross nature of LLVM tools.

According to [this](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html), for the GNU ld the supported parameters for --oformat can be get from "objdump -i" since both program is based on [BFD](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_30.html#SEC30). But ld tools from LLVM seems to be not based on BFD, and I'v tried "--oformat pei" and "--oformat pei-x86-64" based on the result of "objdump -i" from Ubuntu, both doesn't work.

How to know what parameters are supported for the --oformat flag for each LLVM linker tools?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed LLVM linker is not that "cross", e.g. ld.lld only support ELF, it can't accept Unix object file and produce COFF/PE.

Version 6:

```
static bool isOutputFormatBinary(opt::InputArgList &Args) {
    if (auto *Arg = Args.getLastArg(OPT_oformat)) {
        StringRef S = Arg->getValue();
        if (S == "binary")
            return true;
        error("unknown --oformat value: " + S);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This means only "--oformat binary" is supported by ld.lld from linker version 6.

Version 9:

```
static bool isOutputFormatBinary(opt::InputArgList &args) {
    StringRef s = args.getLastArgValue(OPT_oformat, "elf");
    if (s == "binary")
        return true;
    if (!s.startswith("elf"))
        error("unknown --oformat value: " + s);
    return false;
}
```

This is why both "--oformat binary" and "--oformat elf" is supported by ld.lld from linker version 9.